# I'm trying to implement a searchable phonedirectory that can make calls

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, mobile-application

I'm trying to make a searchable phone directory with hardcoded numbers using this website for help:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

I want to make the top Line of each list item to be the contact name and the 2nd line of the list item to be the phone number.

Should someone click on a list_item, the phone would make the call.

I don't know how to go about this. Help would be appreciated.

My current MainActivity Code:

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;


// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listview Data
    String products[] = {"Joe Schmoe", "Bob White"};
    String numbers[]= {"6612225454","5152226666"};
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, numbers);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
}
```

}

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Single ListItem -->

    <!-- Product Name -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_num"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So currently you're overwriting your adapter. That means, only the second adapter is existing:

```
// Adding items to listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, numbers);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Only this one is existing afterwards:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, numbers);
```

Look for a tutorial how to use a ListView and its adapters properly, as it seems you did not quite grasp the concept. Each ListView has one adapter, and this adapter needs to keep track of the items, that means the size of the list, as well as the items and the views they are supposed to represent.

Try something like this for your adapter:

```
private class ContactsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    public ContactsListAdapter(Context ctx, int res, Contact[] l) {
        super(ctx, res, l);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final View v = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        TextView text = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);

                    title.setText(getItem(arg0).getName());
                    text.setText(getItem(arg0).getPhoneNumber());

        return v;
    }
}
```

With this, you would need another class to hold the contacts, something like:

```
public class Contact {
    public String name;
    public String phoneNr;

    public Contact(String name, String phoneNr) { this.name = name; this.phoneNr = phoneNr; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; } 
    public String getPhoneNumber() { return this.phoneNr; } 
}
```

And would pass the ArrayAdapter an array of your contacts.

For example, the initialization might look like this:

```
final Contact[] mContacts = new Contact[] { 
 new Contact('Peter', '+001892734'),
 new Contact('Peter2', '+120932309423')
};

adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, mContacts);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Read some tutorials, websites about this. Then you can add view recycling and other stuff as well.